# Get value -1 to 1 from direction between 2 points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I'm looking to control an AI car and drive it towards a player car. I've calculated a path towards the player car, but i'm having trouble getting the steering angle the AI car should use to travel along the path.

The cars are controlled via a -1 to 1 steering ratio.

This is what i've tried, but the car just goes around in circles.

```
void UpdatePath()
{
    NavMesh.CalculatePath(transform.position, _Target.position, 1 << 0, path);
    DrawPath();

    Vector3 relativePos = path.corners[0] - transform.position;
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos);

    float y = transform.eulerAngles.y;
    float DeltaAngle = Mathf.DeltaAngle(y, targetRotation.y);


   float delta = Mathf.Clamp(DeltaAngle, -1, 1);
```

Any ideas here?

Thank you

Comment: Try `float DeltaAngle = Mathf.DeltaAngle(y, targetRotation.eulerAngles.y);`

Comment: The mere fact that the `NavMesh` class is involved here, and that the broader goal involves an AI of sorts, does not make your question _about_ [tag:navmesh] or [tag:artificial-intelligence]. I've removed those two tags from the question (it's barely _about_ C# and Unity3d for that matter, but conventionally those are more acceptably used as broader tags as you have here).

Comment: The position of a steering wheel does not control the car's direction. It controls the *rate of change* of the car's direction. Its position will need to change over time and then change back over time; the amount depends on how much time or how shallow/steep a turn you wish the car to make.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Min-Max normalization.

```
public float MinMaxNormalization(float point, float MaxPoint, float MinPoint){
        float value = (point - MinPoint) / (MaxPoint - MinPoint); // the value is between 0 and 1
        value *= 2; // now the value is between 0 and 2
        value -= 1; // now the value is between -1 and 1
        return value;
    }
```

I assume MaxPoint = 90.0f and MinPoint = -90.0f , so

```
float MaxPoint = 90.0f;
float MinPoint = -90.0f;
float delta;
delta = MinMaxNormalization(90, MaxPoint , MinPoint); //delta will be 1
delta = MinMaxNormalization(0, MaxPoint , MinPoint); // delta will bi 0
delta = MinMaxNormalization(-90, MaxPoint , MinPoint); // delta will be -1
delta = MinMaxNormalization(45, MaxPoint , MinPoint); // delta will be 0.5
delta = MinMaxNormalization(-45, MaxPoint , MinPoint); // delta will be -0.5
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't follow though, what am I passing into the first parameter? And what determines min and max point?

Comment: The first parameter is your `DeltaAngle` the others is depends whats your max and minimum angle. You can assume 0, 360 or -360, 360. It depends on your code.
`
float DeltaAngle = Mathf.DeltaAngle(y, targetRotation.y);
float delta = MinMaxNormalization(DeltaAngle, MaxEULERANGLEVALUE, MinEULERANGLEVALUE);
`